# Will I be allowed to enter Canada with my almost expired Canadian student visa/permit?

Tags: visa, canada, student-visa

I had to visit my mom and parents after 2 years in Canada and to my misfortune what was supposed to be a one month holiday got extended into 4 months due to my mom's health condition. I haven't completed my post secondary diploma due to several other reasons including this one as well. Theres only 15 days left in my visa and all I need is to grab my things I left there in Canada and return to my place and try to apply for extension from here. I have my flights booked from my hometown to Toronto and I am nervous whether I will be allowed to enter or not. Is it possible to apply for extension in the last 15 days in Canada? If I am allowed to enter in the first place that is.

Comment: Did you take official leave from your program? You may be [out-of-status](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/resources/tools/temp/students/verification.asp) for not maintaining enrollment or not making progress in the program.

Comment: No I did not. I just left the program without notifying the college. I have no purpose to extend the visa or stay in Canada. I just want to take my things I left there and return to my home(country).

Comment: Maybe you could inform us as to what happened and enlighten the community

Answer (score 1):

Nothing related to obtaining a visa or granted entry is entirely safe. Unless you have other issues you haven't mentioned, have not already graduated, etc you will be allowed entry. Make sure you have all your documents in order to present at the airport if requested.

http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/study/study-extend.asp

If you want to extend your stay in Canada as a student, you must apply before the expiry date on your study permit. Complete the Application to Change Conditions or Extend Your Stay in Canada. **You should apply for renewal at least 30 days before your current permit expires**.